# How to query the number of records when there is the DISTINCT keyword in the SQL multi-table join query string?

Tags: sql, sql-server

-- table1 has 1 record

```
select * from t_test01

tid    value   
1      1.5
```

-- table2 has 4 record

```
select * from t_test02

tid    value   
1      1.5
2      1.54
3      1.5
4      1.5
```

--  t_test01.value = t_test02.value,  3 record

```
select t_test01.tid, t_test02.value
from 
t_test01, t_test02
where 
t_test01.value = t_test02.value

tid    value
1      1.5
1      1.5
1      1.5
```

--  DISTINCT t_test01.value = t_test02.value, 1 record

```
select DISTINCT t_test01.tid, t_test02.value
from 
t_test01, t_test02
where 
t_test01.value = t_test02.value

tid    value
1      1.5
```

How to query the number of records when there is the DISTINCT keyword in the SQL multi-table join query string?

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT t_test01.tid, t_test02.value) ??
from 
t_test01, t_test02
where 
t_test01.value = t_test02.value
```

Comment: Please do avoid using the old style of join `from t_test01, t_test02 where  t_test01.value = t_test02.value`. Use the ANSI JOIN syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick-and-dirty approach is to use strings:

```
select count(distinct concat(t_test01.tid, '|', t_test02.value))
from t_test01 join
     t_test02 
     on t_test01.value = t_test02.value;
```

Otherwise, you can use a subquery or CTE:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct t_test01.tid, t_test02.value
      from t_test01 join
           t_test02 
           on t_test01.value = t_test02.value
     ) t;
```

Note the use of proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax in both cases.  **Never** use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

I rewrote the query for clarity, but you can use any query:

```
  WITH T AS (
       select DISTINCT t1.tid, value 
       from 
       t_test01 t1 JOIN t_test02 t2  USING (value)
       )
       SELECT count(*) from T;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does this have an efficiency issue ? I have to get all records for each paging query

Comment: it is as fast as the original query, since it only has to count them. i don't have experience with sql-server but there must be. a way to compare the performance of two queries. Usually using explain followed by the query.